# PHP password_verify always fails with the hash from database (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords

I got a problem with the password_verify() function and the combination with the database (phpMyAdmin).

So when I hash the password by register a new User I use this function:

```
$password_hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

So nothing really special I guess.

It then gets inserted into the database table for users als plain text in a varchar(255).
This should be enough space for the password hash as far as I understood the php manual right.

My problem is now, when I Then try to login with the username und password from this user, the password_verify is alsways false.

Again I dont really do something special there just this:

```
if (isset($_GET['log']) && $_GET['log'] == 1) { 
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $query = 'select user_id, password from user where username = "'.$username.'" and active = 1';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $dbPassword_s = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $dbPassword_s)) {
        //Redirect
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}

echo '<div class="loginoverlay">
    <h1>Loggen Sie sich ein</h1>
    <form action="index.php?section=login&log=1" method="post">
        <div class="float25 textRight">Username / Benutzername</div>
        <div class="float65"><input type="text" name="username" value="'; if(isset($_POST['username'])) {echo $_POST['username'];} echo'" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="float25 textRight">Passwort</div>
        <div class="float65"><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="submitDiv"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="einloggen" /></div>
    </form>
</div>';
```

The interesting part is, when I try to verify the password right after I create it, it works.
So it must be a problem with the database or how I store the password into the database.

My collation for my table is
**utf8mb4_general_ci**

Also tried
**utf8_general_ci**

Both didn't work.

I can't find a solution for this specific error after many tries and searches.

Comment: What do you see when you echo `$dbPassword_s`?

Comment: I get this $2y$10$qw0Oln9VieUbqWM/jyXdne9xbPrrAw9eS4BetUcsVFwRm9Rej5aOy

Comment: And `$_POST['password']` also contains the password entered on the login, as expected? (You used `$username` in your query, so the form data presumably gets processed somewhere before this, but we don't know how/in what way.)

Comment: Oh sorry, the $_POST['password'] contains the right password.
$username is basically just $username=$_POST['username'] - I had a problem with special character a few days before.

I just updated the question to let you know how I get the Information into this script with the error.